# DataAnnotation Regular Expression always returns false for file input

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I've tried so many regular expressions for the `RegularExpression` data annotation to check if the file extension is an image and it always returns false e.g. I've also tried `FileExtension` attribute but it creates an error on the jquery.validation. I'm using ASP.NET MVC 4 Razor

```
[RegularExpression(@"^.*\.(jpg|gif|jpeg|png|bmp)$", 
ErrorMessage = "Please use an image with an extension of .jpg, .png, .gif, .bmp")]
public string MyImage { get; set; }
```

and this is my markup

```
    <div class="editor-field">            
        @Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.DepartmentImage, new { type = "file" })            
        @Html.ValidationMessage("DepartmentImageError")
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.DepartmentImage)
    </div>
```

Could someone show me how to make it work?

Comment: It always shows as an error so I can't post my form Im using MVC 4 Razor

Comment: I don't know I don't know regular expression syntax very well so I'm not sure

Comment: There will always be some type of javascript error or some such way of telling why something won't work.  You either need to enable it in your browser and/or implement logging in your code.

Comment: the backslash escapes the '.' and the @ in the front of the strings means the string will be as it is, no C# code replacement will be done.  E.g., @"\n" will not insert a new line.

Comment: The regex itself works for me.  http://derekslager.com/blog/posts/2007/09/a-better-dotnet-regular-expression-tester.ashx

Comment: I tried you code Matthew and it didn't work for some reason it always an error

Comment: It won't validate for input type="file" field I don't know what todo regular expression is correct

Comment: I've just tried it in a sample project and it worked for me. It checks text of the input type="file" and if valid, binds file name to model just fine.

Answer (score 12):

Try modifying the code like below.

```
@Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.MyImage)
```

**My Suggestion**

**Your form should be like below.**

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Acion", "Conroller", FormMethod.Post, 
                                      new { enctype = "multipart/form-data" }))
{
    <input type="file" name="FileInfo" value="File to Upload" />
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(I => I.FileInfo);
    <button type="submit" name="Upload" value="Upload" />
}
```

[image]

**HttpPostedFileBaseModelBinder**

*When you have a single instance of *HttpPostedFileBase* as an action parameter or a property in model then mapping the file is completely done by the *HttpPostedFileBaseModelBinder* and no value providers are used in this case. You may think why no value providers are used in this case, it's because the source is single and clear i.e. Request.Files collection.*

[image]

**Model**

```
public class UploadFileModel
{
    [FileSize(10240)]
    [FileTypes("jpg,jpeg,png")]
    public HttpPostedFileBase FileInfo { get; set; }
}
```

[image]

**FileSizeAttribute**

[image]

```
public class FileSizeAttribute : ValidationAttribute
{
    private readonly int _maxSize;

    public FileSizeAttribute(int maxSize)
    {
        _maxSize = maxSize;
    }

    public override bool IsValid(object value)
    {
        if (value == null) return true;

        return _maxSize > (value as HttpPostedFileBase).ContentLength;
    }

    public override string FormatErrorMessage(string name)
    {
        return string.Format("The file size should not exceed {0}", _maxSize);
    }
}
```

**FileTypesAttribute**

```
public class FileTypesAttribute: ValidationAttribute
{
    private readonly List<string> _types;

    public FileTypesAttribute(string types)
    {
        _types = types.Split(',').ToList();
    }

    public override bool IsValid(object value)
    {
        if (value == null) return true;

        var fileExt = System.IO
                            .Path
                            .GetExtension((value as
                                     HttpPostedFileBase).FileName).Substring(1);
        return _types.Contains(fileExt, StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase);
    }

    public override string FormatErrorMessage(string name)
    {
        return string.Format("Invalid file type. Only the following types {0} 
                                    are supported.", String.Join(", ", _types));
    }
}
```

**Controller Action Method**

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Upload(UploadFileModel fileModel)
{     
    if(ModelState.IsValid)
    {

    }

    return View(fileModel);
}
```

Comment: nice I'll give that a go and see what I come up with

Comment: That all looks good but I'm just using a string Field for MyImage which is actually called DepartmentImage can you add code for Validating a string instead of HttpPostedFileBase but leave up the code that you have written please.

Answer (score 1):

There is a RegularExpression defined for the field `MyImage` but your `@ValidationMessageFor` validating for DepartmentImage.

This should be

`@Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.MyImage, new { type = "file" })
 @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.MyImage)`