# MVC 4 RegisterModel include Profile Image

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

Within my MVC 4 application when a user registers I'm looking to give them the option to select an image and upload that at the same time as registering - I was just looking at some guidance as to how to do this.

Here is my MVC Model for registering - I've added HttpPostedFileBase to hold the file being posted along with the username and password for new account being registered:

```
public class RegisterModel
{
    [Required]
    [Display(Name = "User name")]
    public string UserName { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [StringLength(100, ErrorMessage = "The {0} must be at least {2} characters long.", MinimumLength = 6)]
    [DataType(DataType.Password)]
    [Display(Name = "Password")]
    public string Password { get; set; }

    [DataType(DataType.Password)]
    [Display(Name = "Confirm password")]
    [Compare("Password", ErrorMessage = "The password and confirmation password do not match.")]
    public string ConfirmPassword { get; set; }

    public HttpPostedFileBase File { get; set; }

}
```

The registration View includes the following input html:

```
<input id="register-avatar"  type="file" name="file" />
```

However when I register, the value for the file is always null...

UPDATE 04-11-2013

I finally created a post which doesn't seem to be covered on how to include a profile image upload with the generic RegisterModel within the MVC 4 Template.  You can find it here - [MVC 4 Add Profile Image to RegisterModel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19776346/mvc-4-add-profile-image-to-registermodel/19776347#19776347)

UPDATE

The problem as mentioned in the comment below is that I did not have the enctype set. For more information have a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4526273/what-does-enctype-multipart-form-data-mean)

Comment: Did you set the enctype of the form to `multipart/form-data`?

Comment: That's exactly the issue - I've updated my question to highlight that.

Comment: **[Please check here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18415206/dataannotation-regular-expression-always-returns-false-for-file-input/18415686#18415686)**

Comment: Is it possible to share the code of that register model and view, so users can add a profile picture?

Comment: @Odrai You've probably worked it out already but I thought I would let you know that I created a post that quickly explains how to add an image to the RegisterModel included in MVC 4 - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19776346/mvc-4-add-profile-image-to-registermodel/19776347#19776347

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The form's encoding type was missing - `multipart/form-data`.

It's explained further [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4526273/what-does-enctype-multipart-form-data-mean).

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, `id` is a stronger identity than `name`, so your `id` attribute should be "file" instead of "register-avatar".

The code inside the view should be:

```
<input type="file" id="File" name="File" />
```

Comment: Thanks for the info but that's not the problem.  It's the enctype as mentioned above.