# MVC 4 Add Profile Image to RegisterModel

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-membership

How do you add the option to upload a profile image to the default RegisterModel in MVC 4?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This answer converts the image to a byte array so that you can then save it in a database.  It can easily be modified if you wanted to save the image to file store.

The code for the View Model.  The important part is the multipart/form-data attribute:

```
 @using (Html.BeginForm("Register", "Account", null, FormMethod.Post, new { enctype = "multipart/form-data" }))
    {
        @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
        @Html.ValidationSummary()

        <fieldset>
            <legend>Registration Form</legend>
            <ol>
                <li>
                    @Html.LabelFor(m => m.UserName)
                    @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.UserName)
                </li>
                <li>
                    @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Password)
                    @Html.PasswordFor(m => m.Password)
                </li>
                <li>
                    @Html.LabelFor(m => m.ConfirmPassword)
                    @Html.PasswordFor(m => m.ConfirmPassword)
                </li>
                <li>
                    <label for="register-avatar">Upload your photo</label>
                    <input id="register-avatar"  type="file" name="ProfileImage" />
                </li>
            </ol>
            <input type="submit" value="Register" />
        </fieldset>
    }
```

The RegisterModel:

```
public class RegisterModel
{
    [Required]
    [Display(Name = "User name")]
    public string UserName { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [StringLength(100, ErrorMessage = "The {0} must be at least {2} characters long.", MinimumLength = 6)]
    [DataType(DataType.Password)]
    [Display(Name = "Password")]
    public string Password { get; set; }

    [DataType(DataType.Password)]
    [Display(Name = "Confirm password")]
    [Compare("Password", ErrorMessage = "The password and confirmation password do not match.")]
    public string ConfirmPassword { get; set; }

    public HttpPostedFileBase ProfileImage { get; set; }

}
```

The AccountController's HTTPPost for the Register.cshtml View:

```
[HttpPost]
    [AllowAnonymous]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult Register(RegisterModel model)
    {

        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            // Attempt to register the user
            try
            {
                WebSecurity.CreateUserAndAccount(model.UserName, model.Password);
                WebSecurity.Login(model.UserName, model.Password);

                MemoryStream target = new MemoryStream();
                model.ProfileImage.InputStream.CopyTo(target);
                byte[] data = target.ToArray();

                var profileImage = new ProfileImage();
                profileImage.Data = data;
                profileImage.MimeType = model.ProfileImage.ContentType;

                /// other code to save the image to the database

                return RedirectToAction("Index", "Profile/" + model.UserName);
            }
            catch (MembershipCreateUserException e)
            {
                ModelState.AddModelError("", ErrorCodeToString(e.StatusCode));
            }
        }

        // If we got this far, something failed, redisplay form
        return View(model);
    }
```

This is a quick run down of how I managed to upload a profile image along with the registration built into the MVC 4 template.

Comment: public HttpPostedFileBase ProfileImage { get; set; }
wouldn't be able to know the type for that property.

Generally the fix is to either make the class' visibility match the property's, or make the property's visibility match the class'. (Make the class public or make the property private or internal accordingly.) Though, to be honest, the fact that you even have a custom implementation of HttpPostedFileBase is a bit strange in the first place...